# instantiate object with array elements as parameters java

Tags: java, reflection, ioc-container, instantiation

I am making an IoC Container in java, using reflection, to auto instantiate dependencies. I've got it working, recursively, but the instantiation is clumsy and not very intuitive.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IoC {

    public void register(Object type)
    {

    }

    public Object resolve(String type) throws Exception {

        // Get class
        Class c = Class.forName(type);

        // Get class constructors
        Constructor[] constructors = c.getConstructors();

        if (constructors.length > 1) {
            throw new Exception(type + " has more than one constructor. Can't auto instantiate!");
        }

        // The one constructor
        Constructor constructor = constructors[0];

        // Get constructor parameter types
        Class[] parameters = constructor.getParameterTypes();

        // ArrayList to hold dependencies
        Object[] dependencies = new Object[parameters.length];

        if (parameters.length > 0) {
            // Get dependencies recursively
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
                dependencies[i] = resolve( parameters[i].getName() );
            }
        }

        if(dependencies.length > 4)
        {
            throw new Exception("Too many dependencies, consider refactoring!");
        }
        else if(dependencies.length == 1) {
            return constructor.newInstance(dependencies[0]);
        }
        else if(dependencies.length == 2) {
            return constructor.newInstance(dependencies[0], dependencies[1]);
        }
        else if(dependencies.length == 3) {
            return constructor.newInstance(dependencies[0], dependencies[1], dependencies[2]);
        }
        else if(dependencies.length == 4) {
            return constructor.newInstance(dependencies[0], dependencies[1], dependencies[2], dependencies[3]);
        }

        return constructor.newInstance();
    }

}
```

As you can see, what i'm doing, is checking the length of the dependencies array, and then passing in the corresponding number of arguments.

So what i'm asking is, is there a way to just pass in the dependencies array when instantiating, and the array elements are automatically passed as separate arguments?

Hope it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `newInstance` method is defined as taking an `Object...` parameter:

```
public T newInstance(Object... initargs)
```

When `newInstance` is called, Java will allow you to pass *either* a list of arguments *or* an `Object[]` array, in which case the elements of the array are passed as if they were individual arguments.  So a simple call to

```
constructor.newInstance(dependencies)
```

will do what you want.

(The tricky part is: since an array is itself an `Object`, how does Java know to treat it as an `Object[]` and pass the elements individually, or to treat it as a single object so that the method is called with *one* argument that is an array?  The answer is that Java assumes the first one.  To pass an `Object[]` as *one* argument, you can cast it to `(Object)`.  This is all figured out at compile time.  The program isn't going to check at run time to see if the array has one element and the element is an `Object[]`, or anything like that.)

One other note: You could also pass an array of anything else, but my Java compiler gives me a warning.

```
String[] strings = new String[4];

constructor.newInstance(strings)

warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
cast to Object for a varargs call
cast to Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
```

To eliminate the warning, assuming you want to pass all four arguments separately:

```
constructor.newInstance((Object[])strings)
```

Comment: Great answer! Had actually thought how i could pass an array as a single argument, and you answered that!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just try it. `Object...` is basically the same thing as `Object[]`, except it allows you to pass several objects as separate arguments instead of constructing the array by yourself. Read about [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Comment: Can't see how i would use that? I don't have variable argument numbers :)

Comment: [The signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) is `Constructor.newInstance(Object...)`, which is basically equivalent to `Constructor.newInstance(Object[])`, so you just need `constructor.newInstance(dependencies)`: the method expects an array of objects, and that's what you have: an array of objects.

Comment: Ahh, ok i understand! That was just too simple, and i even thought i had tried that! Thankyou! :)